# Safe way to check authentication (NodeJS/Express)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I want to make sure that user is authenticated (when logging in user gets session).

```
function isAuthenticated(req, res, next) {

    // do any checks you want to in here

    // CHECK THE USER STORED IN SESSION FOR A CUSTOM VARIABLE
    // you can do this however you want with whatever variables you set up
    if (req.user.authenticated)
        return next();

    // IF A USER ISN'T LOGGED IN, THEN REDIRECT THEM SOMEWHERE
    res.redirect('/');
}
app.get('/hello', isAuthenticated, function(req, res) {
    res.send('look at me!');
});
```

Is there another (more safer) way to check if user is authenticated?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `express-session`:

https://github.com/expressjs/session

Psudo-code:

```
var expressSession = require('express-session');
app.use(expressSession({ secret: 'secret' }));

//...//
app.get('/',function(req,res){
   if (req.session.auth === undefined || req.session.auth === false){
        //handle by redirection to authentication page
   }
   //user is authenitcated
});
```

Comment: What's the `secret` option for?

Comment: the session works by setting a cooky on the the browser. anytime the browse re-conencts, it sends that cookie back to the server. the secred is used as a key for the hash function which is dealing the cookie value

Comment: Is it like a password?

Comment: hmmm... sort of... in a very high level